# Python web scraping requests follow redirect

Tags: python, cookies, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape a web site with the requests module.

Using chrome and inspect elements, I go to the url, fill in a form and click the continue button. Chrome's inspect elements (network documents) shows what chrome sent with post. It also shows multiple cookies.  The site redirects to a url with among other things a session ID.

To simulate this, I try using requests. I take the form data from inspect elements and reformat it to a dictionary. I use requests.session to include the cookies.

```
    import requests

form_data = 'currentCalForm=dep&currentCodeForm=&tripType=oneWay&searchCategory=award&originAirport=JFK&flightParams.flightDateParams.travelMonth=5&flightParams.flightDateParams.travelDay=14&flightParams.flightDateParams.searchTime=040001&destinationAirport=LHR&returnDate.travelMonth=-1000&returnDate.travelDay=-1000&adultPassengerCount=2&adultPassengerCount=1&serviceclass=coach&searchTypeMode=matrix&awardDatesFlexible=true&originAlternateAirportDistance=0&destinationAlternateAirportDistance=0&discountCode=&flightSearch=award&dateChanged=false&fromSearchPage=true&advancedSearchOpened=false&numberOfFlightsToDisplay=10&searchCategory=&aairpassSearchType=false&moreOptionsIndicator=oneWay&seniorPassengerCount=0&youngAdultPassengerCount=0&childPassengerCount=0&infantPassengerCount=0&passengerCount=2'.split('&')

payload = {}
for item in form_data:
    key, value = item.split('=')
    if value:
        payload[key] = value

with requests.session() as s:    
    r = s.post('https://www.aa.com/homePage.do', params = payload, allow_redirects=True)
    print r.headers
    print r.history
    print r.url
    print r.status_code
    with open('x.htm', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(r.text.encode('utf8'))
```

requests, however, does not appear to follow the redirect. history is empty and the url appears to be the data I sent rather than  what the site returned. x.htm shows a web page, but does not contain the info I expected.

From http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#redirection-and-history I expected r.url to contain the redirected url and r.history to contain an http response code.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you know how to user `wireshark`?

Comment: Try it in the browser with javascript disabled as request will not parse or run javascript. I am also not sure if it follows meta redirects which the site may be doing.

Comment: @OfirIsrael I thought wireshark was to monitor low level web traffic. How to use here?

Comment: @justinfay It doesn't work with javascript disabled, but there seems to be many other pages which use javascript that work with request.  Which library would you recommend using?

Comment: It might help understanding what went wrong. If you got a redirection response and didn't follow it etc.

Comment: @OfirIsrael request does not appear to redirect. r.url appears to be my params rather than the redirected url (see the linked request doc). r.history is an empty list rather than a response code. The returned page does not have any of the expected information. It does return 200 as the status code

Comment: @justinfay I believe you are right. Looking at the html output in an editor, says I must have javascript enabled and recommends updating my browser. Displaying the page in my browser did not include this language.

Comment: some times the headers make a difference i see you didnt set any headers, give it a try. also double check the parameters you send. if you do exactly the same as the browser you will get exactly the same result.

Comment: @FooBarUser I'm cutting and pasting the forms data parameters from my browser (see edit in the question). Exactly what do you mean by setting headers?

Comment: @foosion go [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#session-objects) and ctrl+f headers

Comment: @FooBarUser the request-headers, as reported by inspect element, are essentially a series of cookies. I thought requests.sessions() captured cookies and fed them back. If not, how would I find the cookies the web site is setting so that I could feed back to requests.headers? Also, the web site is creating a sessionID that it's adding to the redirected URL and I see no way to get that.

Comment: @foosion i think i may be able to do it, i'll give a try tonight and let you know (need a break now). from my personal experience 99% of the times the redirect was not ok, the request sent was wrong ( either headers or params). usualy i use [httpfox](https://addons.mozilla.org/En-us/firefox/addon/httpfox/) to find what request headers are sent, and also the parameters of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok what you do seems to be wrong. i am not sure how you decided to sent a post on `https://www.aa.com/homePage.do`, but that seems to be a get and doesnt take the params you send. when you click search your browser sends this post: `https://www.americanairlines.co.uk/reservation/searchFlightsSubmit.do;jsessionid=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX` and parameters:

```
currentCalForm=dep
currentCodeFrom=
tripType=roundTrip
originAirport=LAX
flightParams.flightDateParams.travelMonth=10
flightParams.flightDateParams.travelDay=24
flightParams.flightDateParams.searchTime=040001
destinationAirport=JFK
returnDate.travelMonth=10
returnDate.travelDay=31
returnDate.searchTime=400001
adultPassengerCount=1
adultPassengerCount=1
childPassengerCount=0
hotelRoomCount=1
serviceclass=coach
searchTypeMode=matrix
awardDatesFlexible=true
originAlternateAirportDistance=0
destinationAlternateAirportDistance=0
discountCode=
flightSearch=revenue
dateChanged=false
fromSearchPage=true
advancedSearchOpened=false
numberOfFlightsToDisplay=10
searchCategory=
aairpassSearchType=false
moreOptionsIndicator=
seniorPassengerCount=0
youngAdultPassengerCount=0
infantPassengerCount=0
passengerCount=1
```

This will then give you an html back. preety mach you have to send all requests send in the browser. it might be easier for you to do it with selenium.

i found this using [httpfox](https://addons.mozilla.org/En-us/firefox/addon/httpfox/) probably is similar to chrome networks.

Comment: where do you get the xxxxxxx for jsessionid=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX? The main problem I've been having is figuring out how to get the session ID that is part of the redirect URL.

Comment: its in the cookies: JSESSIONID

Comment: if i hit the homepage it redirects to https://www.americanairlines.co.uk/homePage.do?locale=en_GB which has a cookie JSESSIONID

Comment: The JSESSIONID did the trick to get to the next step.  Still having issues, but if I can't resolve them, I'll post another question.